# Can the Android Metamask Extension be used with DApps?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, android

I've successfully downloaded the Metamask Firefox Add-on, and imported my wallet into it.

However I'm failing to see how I can use this add-on from within my DApp like I do on Chrome, using the Metamask Chrome Extension.

What are the full capabilities of the Firefox add-on ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the MetaMask extension in Chrome and Firefox for testing purposes and it works exactly the same in both.

Check with MetaMask documentaion if there were changes in the recommended practices to connect from a dapp https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/.

Comment: I have been testing my dApp successfully within Chrome using the Metamask extension, but not through firefox on android. 

I can't get the dApp to recognise the installed extension. 

I setup my extension and imported my wallet. Do I need to integrate it in any different way than the Chrome (on mac) Extension version ?

Comment: @user4251864 It is better to create a new question and show the  code you use to connect with web3 provider.